# Determinar largura de coluna do Bootstrap quando detectar overflow na div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Atualmente a distribuição das colunas do Boostrap está fixa no tamanho 2, exemplo: `col-lg-2`, porém dentro dessa coluna há uma `<ul>` com vários `<li>`, e quando ocorre o overflow a `<ul>` é exibida em duas colunas.

Acontece que quando a lista é pequena e a `<ul>` é exibida em apenas uma coluna fica sobrando espaço e fica desalinhado.

Gostaria de especificar o tamanho das colunas de forma dinâmica para que ficasse tudo corretamente alinhado.

A `<ul>` também é gerada de forma dinâmica usando PHP e o para que ocorra o overflow fiz o que está aceito como resposta  [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315856/configurar-css-para-gerar-uma-nova-coluna-quando-atingir-o-overflow) que eu mesmo fiz a alguns dias atrás.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que os espaços que estão demarcados em preto sejam removidos quando não houver overflow. Um exemplo de overflow é nas categorias Menina e Baby, quando ocorre o overflow ele quebra em duas colunas.

O tamanho das colunas está fixo em 2, gostaria de gerá-los de forma dinâmica ou alterar pelo css quando houvesse overflow.

Comment: Leo coloca o seu código ai na pergunta. coloca de forma que a gente possa testar e ver o erro que da quando tem poucas LI, se possível adicione um printe de como está e como vc gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: Vou tirar um print e mostrar como a tela está atualmente...